# libxml2.dylib, libz.dylib, libicucore.dylib, and libc++ missing from xcode project, causing linker errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker-errors, dylib

I think I messed something up with the libxml2.dylib, libz.dylib, libicucore.dylib, and libc++.dylib files, and then 1. appear red in the project and 2. cause linker errors.

[image: red files]

And in link binary with libraries:

[image: link binary with libraries]

And if i delete them and try to re-add them, they don't appear as a file to add.

The linker error I am getting is

```
ld: library not found for -lxml2
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can't add libxml2.dylib etc to your project anymore then you probably deleted them accidentally (perhaps when removing a framework from a project?) - In that case re-installing Xcode should help.

Comment: The reinstall worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
-lxml2
```

to your project's "Other linker flags"

Comment: The "Other linked flags" is not in the same folder in Xcode. You need to search those keywords again in the setting.